# How to find controls within a Table Object?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to find textbox controls within a Table object without writing it to the page first. I need an efficient method of finding these controls so as to not slow to down the website.

The table is created by calling a new object of report_writer type

```
Public ReportTable As Table
Public SectionID As Integer
Public ErrorList As List(Of String)
Public Sub New(ByVal SectionID As Integer, ByVal InitiativeID As Integer, ByVal AgencyID As Integer, ByVal ReportID As Integer, ByVal Printed As Boolean, ByVal Blank As Boolean)
    Me.SectionID = SectionID
    ErrorList = New List(Of String)
    ReportTable = WriteSection(SectionID, InitiativeID, AgencyID, Blank, Printed, ReportID, 1)
End Sub
```

show above and stores it in the ReportTable variable in the object.

After the table is created a few functions such as Autocomplete and validation need to operate on the table to edit the formatting of the table for the user before the table is eventually written to the page.

The problem I am running into is that FindControl is not working within the Autocomplete and validation methods and is giving a Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

```
'Finds the Table all of the controls are stored in
 Dim matrixTable As Table = ReportTable
 Dim TextBoxValues As New ArrayList
 Dim txt As TextBox
    'Loops through each item in the Array Lists of Heading and QuestionIDs to find a specific Textbox 
    For index As Integer = 0 To (HeadingCount - 1)
            txt = matrixTable.FindControl("txt_" & RightHeadingGroup(index) & "-" & RightQuestionGroup(index))
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text) Then
                 TextBoxValues.Add(0)
            Else
                TextBoxValues.Add(txt.Text)
            End If

    Next
```

Above is an example of how I am trying to find the textboxes within the page.

[image: This is what the final table will resemeble]

Above is what the table when finished will resemble.

Comment: Read this [Control.FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) and maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356108/using-string-as-a-name-of-a-variable)

Comment: Is this a web app, WinForms, WCF?

Comment: This is a web app.